# R string_extract matching in between two strings

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to use str_extract from the stringr package to match a string in between two other strings.

I have the string

```
sum(jan)
```

and I want it to return

```
jan
```

I've tried

```
str_extract('sum(jan)', '(?<=sum\\().*(?=\\)')
```

but I'm getting the error

```
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
```

It works with for example in the below, so I'm assuming it has to do with how I'm trying to match the parenthesis

```
> str_extract('rooasdfboo', '(?<=roo).*(?=boo)')
[1] "asdf"
```

Any help is appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: You missed the closing `)` in `(?=\\)` - > `(?=\\))`

Comment: It's just a typo. Use `str_extract('sum(jan)', '(?<=sum\\().*(?=\\))')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it :

```
(?<=sum\().*(?=\))
```

See [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Cxbtgp/1)

The problem is the double escape character, by using two of them you're actually escaping the character '\', which then messes with the parenthesis.